# Sending emails from Excel (2013) from an alternate (not main) Outlook (2013) account. (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I've managed to get Excel to create emails in Outlook, from an alternate account, not my main one.

The trouble is, they just sit in the second account Outbox, doing nothing. Note that I can send files from this account manually just fine.

```
Dim MyOlApp As Object
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim AttachName As String
Dim SendTo As String
Dim CCTo As String
Dim E, F, G As Integer
Dim Sys_Date As String
'Sys_Date = Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY")

F = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"))
'G = F


For E = 2 To F

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
AttachName = Cells(E, 2).Value
SendTo = Cells(E, 5).Value
CCTo = Cells(E, 6).Value

Set MyOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = MyOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\localDocuments\2 - Reporting\1 - Guides + Sample Data etc\Email.oft")
MyItem.Display

On Error Resume Next
With MyItem
    Set .SendUsingAccount = MyOlApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    .To = SendTo
    .CC = CCTo
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Action required: " & AttachName
    'You can add other files also like this
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\localDocuments\2 - Reporting\Reports\" & AttachName & ".xlsx")
    .Display
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set MyItem = Nothing
Set MyOlApp = Nothing


Next E
```

UPDATE:

Whilst I've not been able to find the actual cause of the issue.  I have managed to find a very simple fix.

I've created a new Outlook Profile, with just the alternate account that we need to send by and it works just fine.  This works perfectly as the code is only used once a week once a 3hr report has been run.

I can see that it would not be applicable to someone who was sending regular (throughout the day) emails in this way.

For Reference, you access the profiles by WIN 8 SEARCH / MAIL (filter by SETTINGS), select MAIL and then VIEW PROFILES.

Comment: this probably has to do with the `Send/Recieve` feature in Outlook. I suspect the `.Send` is referring only to the main account? This [link](http://www.slovaktech.com/code_samples.htm#SendReceive) may help get you the code you need to run to get it to send. This is a bit of conjecture, so I hope it's useful.

Comment: I'll take a look at that later.  For now I've set up a new profile with JUST the alternate account that I need to send from and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple fix.

I've created a new Outlook Profile, with just the alternate account that we need to send by and it works just fine.

I acknowledge that it would not be a good fix to someone who was sending regular (throughout the day) emails in this way.